# Is it possible to blend a variable assignment with a condition test?

Tags: python

I often have code similar to

```
a = somefunction()
if a:
    do_something()
```

Is there in Python a construction which would blend the initialization with the condition test? Something like

```
if a = somefunction():
    do_something()
```

which would test `a` after it has been assigned a value via `somefunction()`?

Comment: Your first approach is the best thing you can do.

Comment: why would you assign a if you are not going to use it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I will use it (and this is why I assign what the function returns to a variable as opposed to directly using it as mentioned in Alex's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this; an `if` statement must have a condition- so putting an assignment in it will cause a `SyntaxError`. *Your first example is the best*, but unless you need `a` again later then this:

```
if somefunction():
    do_something()
```

Should suffice.

Comment: Thanks. The first example works fine, I just wanted to reduce the possible clutter (and I need `a` afterwards)

Comment: @WoJ Glad I could help. When the grace period has passed, would you mind accepting with the tick to show that the issue is closed? Thank you. :)